# What should I do to specify an optional action parameter for cleos?

Tags: smart-contract, cleos, transactions, action

I wrote an action that has an optional parameter, as something like:

```
[[eosio::action]] void foo(..., const std::optional<name>& recipient);
```

Then in the generated .abi, it is represented as:

```
{"name": "recipient", "type": "name?"}
```

But I couldn't find a way to specify (or, not specify) the optional parameter for cleos. Itried without specifying the optional parameter, `{..., "recipient": ""}`, etc., all in vain.
What should I do to specify an optional action parameter for cleos?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to specify the value for optional param, just pass value like normal type. For not specifying value, use `null`.

`{..., "recipient": "eosio"}` or `{..., "recipient": null}`